# beamer temporal problem

Tags: beamer, positioning

I am interested in appearing the following sequence , progressively, on the same location
A
AB
ABC
ABCD
ABCDE

The temporal instruction allows one for 3 elements to appear progressively.

The overlay instruction or the onslide one could do it.
But when then on the same frame I create a distinct block, where I want to create a new text appearing progressively with itemize,  I have problems.

Do you know how to do it ?

I thank you in advance

Comment: As in `a\pause b\pause c\pause d\pause e`? Otherwise please create a minimal working example so that we can understand your trouble with this block, or whatever is causing your problem.

Comment: Thanks again but  I am not sure that I explained clearly my answer.

Comment: I need to overwrite A by AB then overwrite AB by ABC etc.

Comment: At the same time I need to have progressive items on an itemise just after the progressive appearance of A, AB, ABC etc. Thanks

Comment: OK, I still have now idea, what the actual question is about, so just a guess: `\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
 
 \begin{frame}
  some text
  
  \only<+>{a}
  \only<+>{ab}
  \only<+>{abc}
  \only<+->{abcd}
  
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
   \item first item
   \item second item
  \end{itemize}
  
 \end{frame} 
 
\end{document}`

Comment: Hello Yes that works as I wish.

Answer (score 1):

I admit, I still do not really understand your question, but if you want to replace text, `only` is a simple solution. The `<+>` overlay argument means, that the text will be displayed on the next slide, `<+->` that it is displayed on the next and all following.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\begin{document} 
    \begin{frame} 
        some text 

        \only<+>{a} 
        \only<+>{ab} 
        \only<+>{abc} 
        \only<+->{abcd} 

        \begin{itemize}[<+->] 
            \item first item 
            \item second item 
        \end{itemize} 

    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is OK.
My problem is resolved.
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @kate.marion Then please consider accepting my answer (by clicking on the checkmark ✓) :)

Comment: Where is that checkmark ? I do not see any...

Comment: @kate.marion It should be on the left side of question, below the arrows with the votes. http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1853/36296

Comment: i still do not see anything

Comment: @kate.marion mmmm, then I don't know. But thanks for trying! It would even have given you 2 rep points :(